# Reweighted Range Voting

Tags: algebra-precalculus, voting-theory

I'm trying to create a voting system that implements RRV, yet I'm unable to fully understand the explanation from an example that [I found at rangevoting.org](http://www.rangevoting.org/RRV.html). I'm struggling to understand the following part

> each ballot is given a new weight = 1/(1+SUM/MAX), where SUM is the
>   sum of the scores that ballot gives to the winners-so-far, while MAX
>   is the maximum allowed score (e.g. MAX=99 if allowed scores are in the
>   range 0 to 99).

I have the following table which explains what I've achieved so far. I'm not sure if that is correct.

[image: Excel Table Showing My Approach]

On the image on the second "third round formula" (supposed to be fourth) please consider the last cell (b9) to be (b16) it is a typo, and also the arrows to the right are pointing to the formula rather than the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's all wrong :)

A voter's score for a candidate in each later round should be equal to the score **that voter** gave in the first round, divided by one plus (the sum of the scores they gave to already-elected candidates divided by (the maximum score times the number of candidates elected.))

Example: round 2, voter 1, candidate 1.00. The score should be $5 / ( 1 + (7/9) )$ or $2.8125$; NOT equal $5 / ( 1 + (37/9) )$ or $0.978$.

You're dividing by the **total** score for the candidate, when you should be dividing by the **voter's** score for the candidate (which, unfortunately, is a quite-a-bit-messier equation to do in Excel.)

---

Oh wait; since you're not dynamically determining the winner, the equation isn't so bad. B9 should `=1/(1+B5/9)*(B2)` (which I'd simplify as `B2*(1+B5/9))`.

Another error: always base the score on the first-round (initial) scores! so B16 should be `=1/(1+((B5+B2)/(9+9)))*B2` (a moot point, since candidate 1.00 was already elected, but I hope you get the idea.)

Comment: Let me see if I got it right. So, for round 4 it would be B2x(1+((B5+B2+B3)/(3x9). Oh, and one more question. To make it dynamic do I have to calculate every voters's scores and then choose of all the results, or am I able to sum up all the voters for candidate 1,2,3 etc and then run the equation on the final results to see the order of winners?